# Why I failed to use the \foreach command to connect the points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have a collection of points and I want use `tikz` package to connect them by using the `\foreach` command to scan all the data. But I failed :(   Here is a mwe

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \mx/\my/\mz in {(1,1)/(2,2)/(3,3)}{
    \draw \my--\my--\mz;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wonder why I failed and how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to hide the commas from the TikZ parser otherwise it thinks that the array is `(1`,`1)/(2`,`2)/(3`,`3)`. Also you are missing the closing brace of the body of the loop.

```
\foreach \mx/\my/\mz in {{(1,1)}/{(2,2)}/{(3,3)}}{\draw \my--\my--\mz;}
```

should work. Note that your loop is spinning only once.

Comment: It works. Thanks for your answer and notes :)